# Creating Amazon Kinesis Data Generator Stack on different Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to generate a cloudformation stack provided by AWS [here](http://yashtraining-kdg.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/help.html). When I click the Create a Cognito User with CloudFormation button, it directs me to AWS console CloudFormation page on us-west-2 (Oregon), from there its pretty much self explanatory. The problem is, the company that I'm working on only allows work on us-west-1 (N. California). I have tried looking over the CloudFormation template itself and I cant find any region being mentioned. I have also asked this question in AWS developer forum but no one has responded, and I'm wondering if anyone here knows how to generate that particular stack on any region other than us-west-2 (oregon)? Thanks!

Comment: Just copy the YAML\JSON to the destination region.

Comment: tried that too just before i made this question, also didnt work

Comment: https://imgur.com/vma13ul

Comment: https://imgur.com/1XWBOCP copy the template to the region you want

Comment: I'm getting this error https://imgur.com/a/8jJUvW2

Comment: Looks like there's an issue we this, what are you trying to achive? i might have some samples that could be helpful

Comment: I'm trying to generate a script where I can generate random data (JSON format) and send it to AWS through Kinesis constantly and stop it whenever I want or only at a certain time. Also, I'm not going to hardcode access and secret keys to the script. Before I made the script, I found out about Amazon Kinesis Data Generator and it pretty much does everything I want including the UI, except for the problems that occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for that. I used to face the same problem, as my company policy was set to not use us-west-2, therefore I couldn't use the CloudFormation JSON script provided by [Amazon Kinesis Data Generator](https://awslabs.github.io/amazon-kinesis-data-generator/web/help.html).

What I did was:

1. Download CloudFormation JSON script by Amazon Kinesis Data Generator in your local machine. CloudFormation JSON script download link can be found Amazon Kinesis Data Generator Help [page](https://awslabs.github.io/amazon-kinesis-data-generator/web/help.html)
2. Download the source code. The source code download link can be found in Amazon Kinesis Data Generator Help [page](https://awslabs.github.io/amazon-kinesis-data-generator/web/help.html).
3. In your AWS account, go to S3 and create a S3 bucket in the region that you are allowed to create. Name it whatever you want.
4. Upload the source code downloaded in step2 to the created bucket in step3.
5. Edit CloudFormation JSON script downloaded in step1. Inside of script, change bucket name inside of Lambda function to the name of bucket you created in step3.
6. Go to CloudFormation and create the stack by uploading your edited script.

One thing that you need to keep in mind implementing this workaround is that if there are any changes to source code by AWSLAB, or any newer version of source code comes to life, you will have to manually check and update it to your bucket.

I hope it was clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have created JMeter plugin to publish data records in Kinesis Data Stream.

https://github.com/JoseLuisSR/awsmeter

It works very well and you don't need use any aditional AWS service to publish event in Kinesis as Kinesis Data Generator does, where you could pay aditional charges for services like Cognito, Cloudformation, Lambda that are need to build and deploy KDG.

You just need AWS IAM user with programmatic access, download JMeter and install awsmeter plugin.

If you have questions or comments let me know.

Thanks.